# Changing the entire chain gear mechanism

Tags: chain, crankset, cassette

I have a [Lapierre shaper 100](http://www.culturevelo.com/Shaper-100-9577).

I am looking to change my entire chain mechanism as some of these parts need to be changed. I have selected my components, and I am hoping you can tell me if these parts will be compatible.

- [Shimano Claris FC-2403 crankset](http://www.rosebikes.com/product/detail/aid:669551)
- [Shimano CS-HG51 8-speed cassette](http://www.rosebikes.com/product/detail/aid:520178)
- [Shimano Claris RD-2400 GS rear derailleur](http://www.rosebikes.com/article/shimano-claris-rd-2400-gs-rear-derailleur/aid:669574)
- [Shimano CN-HG71 chain](http://www.rosebikes.com/article/shimano-cn-hg71-chain/aid:739579)
- [Shimano Claris FD-2403 B front derailleur](http://www.rosebikes.com/article/shimano-claris-fd-2403-b-front-derailleur/aid:669566)

I would really appreciate your thoughts

Comment: As a rule of thumb, any part in the 2400 range will be compatible with any other part in the 2400 range, that's just how Shimano numbering works. Second, you don't mention shifter - is the one you already have compatible? Third, before you do anything, cost this all up, you may be surprised how expensive it is to do this kind of upgrade piecemeal. Fourth, why? Claris is still pretty low-end gear, would you realy gain much?

Comment: Why do you do this? As @PeteH mentioned, it will be quite expensive. Just change the parts that really need to changed because they are broken or worn out.

Comment: I need to change my chain and rear derailleur. The chain is hyper extended and the rear derailleur is bent. Looking at the cassette it some teeth appear worn out compared to others. I read some posts that it is good idea to change the cassette and the chain together this way one bad part doesn't hurt the the other. I want to change the front derailleur to match with the rear one, because currently when the chain is in the smallest gear in the front, I have a range of the lowest 3 gears in the rear, which is quite annoying. I decided a full new mechanism might just make things work smoothly.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the shifters should work as they are 8x3.

Comment: Your front derailleur is probably fine with adjustment. And why are you changing the crankset?

Comment: "...when the chain is in the smallest gear in the front, I have a range of the lowest 3 gears in the rear ..." that's rather a problem of poor adjustment and/or trimming. Normally it is possibly to adjust the low or high position of the front derailleur when shifting from cog 3 to 4 to keep the chain from rubbing on the plate of the derailleur. The way a FD works is quite crude and similar throughout the range, the materials may just be more sophisticated higher up.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing only the technical compatibility, if you currently have a Shimano 8x3 setup, and you wish to upgrade to another Shimano 8x3 setup, then any Shimano 8-speed road parts should be fine.

So that includes Claris, Sora, Tiagra etc. as long as it's 8-speed kit. Same goes for the chain.

I mention Sora and Tiagra just in case you're able to source these "old" parts at a decent price, off eBay or something.

Comment: You can even substitute an 9 speed rear derailleur. For road parts, 10 speed is also compatible.

Comment: yeah, there are a few variations. My answer was coming from a "keep it simple" standpoint :)